# How can I force Jpanel to immediately repaint in Java?

Tags: java, swing, repaint

Here is my code

```
boolean boo = true;

ItemListener itemListener = new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        boo= false;         
        aSwingObj.repaint();
        boo = true;
     }
}
```

I want the repaint() method to run while boo is set to false, before it becomes true .

The problem is that repaint() function is only executed after the variable boo has been set to true again. I have tried other methods like revalidate(), validate() but it didn't work. How should I fix my code?

Comment: You have a design problem. The itemStateChanged is only a single event. There it should not change the state of a variable twice. Maybe you need a Timer. So you set the state, paint the component and then a few second later reset the state?

Answer (score 0):

This is an [**XY problem**](http://xyproblem.info). You don't want to force JPanel to immediately repaint. You want to enter a particular state immediately before painting begins and exit that state as soon as painting is over.

One way of accomplishing that would in fact be to enter that state, force a repaint right on the spot, and then exit that state.  But as you have seen, this is a bit hard to accomplish.

So, another approach is to create a new class that does `extend JPanel` (or whatever the class of `aSwingObj` is) so that you can override the `paintComponent()` method and make it exit your special state once painting is done.

So, the `paintComponent()` method of your extended `JPanel` would look like this:

```
 @Override
 public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) 
 {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        resetBoo();
 }
```

where `resetBoo()` is a method which does `boo = true;`

Comment: (1-) You can't control when the paintComponent() method is invoked. Threrfore a painting method should not change the state of an object, only paint the current state.

Comment: @camickr judging by the code provided by the OP, the state is of interest only to the code that does the painting, so it should be all right.  In any case, if you can provide a better solution, I will remove my answer.  If not, my answer stands, as it does provide a solution which will cover the OP's needs.

Comment: `judging by the code provided` - the OP doesn't understand how Swing painting works and therefore has a design problem. Without fully understanding the requirement we can't provide a proper solution.

Comment: @camickr yes, I suppose it is an "XYZ problem".

Comment: `I suppose it is an "XYZ problem".` - yes, as you stated in your first sentence.

Comment: No, I mean, XYZ as in, 3 degrees of indirection instead of 2 degrees of indirection: there is a real problem X hiding somewhere, then there is a perceived solution Y for X which is also elusive, so then there is a perceived solution Z for Y which is also elusive.